# IndexError: list index out of range / Difficulty calling a list using OOP

Tags: python, oop

I'm new to coding and have been teaching myself python through the 'Learn Python the Hard Way' tutorial and am currently making a simple game. So far everything seems to be working, except for the fact that I can't figure out how to properly call a list one of my Classes makes with other Classes.

```
class engine(object):
    def __init__(self,world,days,character):
        self.world = world
        self.days = days
        self.character = character

    def letsdoit(self):
        self.world.worldbuilder()
```

This is the block meant to actually run the game, lines 9 onward are omitted because they aren't relevant.

world.worldbuilder is the function which creates the map on which the game is actually played.

```
class World(self, width, height):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def worldbuilder(self):
        map = []
        for x in xrange(self.width):
            z = []
            for y in xrange(self.height):
                z.append(self.tiletype())
            map.append(z)
        return map
```

World.tiletype just randomly generates a tile then resets. When I instantiate an object of World and run worldbuilder (except I print map instead of returning it) it all works perfectly fine. However when I refer to map in conjecture with objects other than World which engine runs, I get errors. The most common is:

```
IndexError: list out of range
```

Specifically I get it in response to:

```
class player(object):
    def __init__(self, World):
        self.x = randint(1,World.width)
        self.y = randint(1,World.height)
        self.tilestore = map([self.x][self.y])
```

Even when I set player.tilestore to equal a generic tile, I run into TypeErrors where it says my 'built_in_function_or_method' item has no attribute 'get_item' when I refer to map in other places.

I have tried setting list = self.world.worldbuilder(), then calling list instead of map, but then I run into the exact same problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to call `worldbuilder`, so maybe you can call it before using map:

```
class player(object):
    def __init__(self, World):
        self.x = randint(1,World.width)
        self.y = randint(1,World.height)
        map = World.worldbuilder()
        self.tilestore = map[self.x][self.y]
```

And as mentioned by Brionius, using map is a bad idea (unless you want to use the built-in function). This lead to the misleading error message.
Using the same name (World) for a class and an instance is also bad.

Comment: I needed to establish map as an attribute of player, but other than that this worked, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The `IndexError` is caused by incorrect list index syntax, and the `TypeError` is caused by a namespace collision.  To fix the `IndexError`, you should use this syntax:

```
self.tilestore = world_map[self.x][self.y]
```

The `TypeError` is caused by a namespace collision.  In `player.init` You are using the variable `map` without initializing `map` in the local namespace, so `map` refers to the global namespace, where it contains a reference to the builtin `map` function.  You need to pass `map` in as an argument to `player.init` like this

```
class player(object):
    def __init__(self, world, map):
```

or get it from a `World` instance like this

```
class player(object):
    def __init__(self, world):
        self.x = randint(1,world.width)
        self.y = randint(1,World.height)
        self.tilestore = world.map([self.x][self.y])
```

You should also, as I did above, change the argument `World` to `world`, to avoid another namespace collision, between the class name `World` and the instance of the class, called `World`.

Another problem that can cause the `IndexError` is your use of `randint`.  Assuming you're using the [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) function, for arguments `a` and `b`, it generates numbers such that `a <= N <= b`.  Note that this range is inclusive on both sides.  That means that sometimes `self.x` is equal to `world.width`, and `self.y` is equal to `world.height`.  Both of those values are out of range due to the way you constructed `world.map`.  Here's the fix:

```
class player(object):
    def __init__(self, world):
        self.x = randint(1,world.width - 1)
        self.y = randint(1,World.height - 1)
        self.tilestore = world.map([self.x][self.y])
```

You'll have to make similar changes anywhere you are indexing your worldmaps.

Comment: I tried both of these suggestions.
When I tried the first (after replacing all instances of 'map' with 'mapp'), I still got a 'IndexError: list index out of range'.
When I tried the second (using world.worldbuilder instead of world.map) I got the same error

Comment: I looked over the code again, and found another `IndexError` cause.  See if the addition above fixes your problem.

Comment: This helped sort out a lot of small problems with my code. I also caught another mistake in my code similar to the one you pointed out with your more recent edit.
It is working now, ultimatly what I did was set self.mapp = world.worldbuilder(), then run self.character.mapp in engine.letsdothis. Thank you both for your help.